# How can I change a parameter of a method depending on which UITableView row was tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm a new programmer, and I'm having some troubles implementing this. I have a couple of classes set up in my data model like so:

I create my object here:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class PracticePads {

var padTitle: String

var padImage: UIImage

var  soundPreset: Int

init(pad: UIImage, title: String, preset: Int ) {

    self.padImage = pad
    self.padTitle = title
    self.soundPreset = preset
}

}
```

then another file where I create an array like this:

```
class PracticePadBank {

var list = [PracticePads]()

init(){

        let pad1 = PracticePads(pad: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Hard Neoprene Pad"), title: "Pad 1", preset: 0)
        let pad2 = PracticePads(pad: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Hard Neoprene Pad"), title: "Pad 2", preset: 0)

        let pad3 = PracticePads(pad: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Hard Neoprene Pad"), title: "Pad 3", preset: 0)
        let pad4 = PracticePads(pad: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Hard Neoprene Pad"), title: "Pad 4", preset: 0)
        let pad5 = PracticePads(pad: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Hard Neoprene Pad"), title: "Pad 5", preset: 0)            
        list.append(pad1)
        list.append(pad2)
        list.append(pad3)
        list.append(pad4)
        list.append(pad5) 
}
}
```

In another ViewController I've setup a UITableView that lets the user pick a "Practice Pad" like this:

```
class ChooseViewController: UIViewController {

var pads: [PracticePads] = []
let allPads = PracticePadBank()
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


  override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
    pads = allPads.list

}

}

extension ChooseViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pads.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let pad = pads[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PadCell") as! PadCell

    cell.setPad(pad: pad)

    return cell

}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self .performSegue(withIdentifier: "BlackToDetail", sender: nil)

    }  
}
```

This UITableView would take the user to another VC where they can pick different exercises.. I have UIButtons for now set up to transition to yet another VC where the method is that I want to change the parameter of (preset) based on the row tapped:

```
func loadSF2PresetIntoSampler(preset:UInt8)  {

    guard let bankURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Pad Sounds", withExtension: "sf2") else {
        print("could not load sound font")
        return
    }

    do {
        try sampler.loadSoundBankInstrument(at: bankURL, program: preset,bankMSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultMelodicBankMSB),bankLSB: UInt8(kAUSampler_DefaultBankLSB))
    } catch {
        print("error loading sound bank instrument")
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to get this to happen.

Thanks a million in advance for any help here!!

*** I have one more question with this - Everything has been working great if the ViewControllers in question are right next to each other in the stack, but I need to somehow pass the data through about 3 other view controllers... I've tried to use the prepare for Segue method as listed below in the answer, but the print statement on the ViewController I want to call the method on says that the cell is nil. I'm not sure how I can persist the data from the first ViewController (where I am getting the cell) to the ViewController where I want to access the index of he first ViewController's cell. Hope this makes sense! Let me know if I should show my currently updated code to help illustrate this... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `indexPath.row`

```
 self .performSegue(withIdentifier: "BlackToDetail", sender: indexPath.row)
```

//

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "BlackToDetail" {
       let nextScene = segue.destination as! NextViewController 
       nextScene.selectedRow = sender as! Int
    }

}
```

//

```
class NextViewController: UIViewController {
     var selectedRow:Int?
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for trying to help here. I tried to add this code, and in the destination VC (the one you are calling NextViewController - Mine is called 'ViewController') I'm getting a SIGABRT error that says:  Could not cast value of type 'SampleSequencer.BlackViewController' (0x10a3b2520) to 'SampleSequencer.ViewController' (0x10a3b2728). also, I'm not sure how to proceed after your example - as in actually changing the values (I was planning to make a fun that would do this) Thank you!

Comment: how did you cast the value in prepareForSegue , Does nextVC is BlackViewController??

Comment: Hi, I'm just a little confused - probably why I'm having the problem! So, from ChooseVC, it goes to BlackVC, and then to MainVC, then the method I want to access is in "ViewController" I took the code you provided and entered this:  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "BlackToDetail" {
            let nextScene = segue.destination as! ViewController
            nextScene.selectedRow = sender as? Int
        }
    } I am guessing that it is because the segue goes to black vc and the segue I need is two VC away called "nextVC"?

Comment: I changed segue identifier to proper name "nextVC" and the crash stops. Now I am wondering how to try and change the parameter?

Comment: select any cell then print selectedRow in viewDidLoad of nextVC

Comment: Ok, did that, added print("cell is at \(selectedRow)") to (where nextVC segue goes to) ViewController's viewDidLoad
 and it prints off "selected row is nil"

Comment: don't conncet the cell in IB as the source of the segue connect the VC itself

Comment: Ok, after reworking some things on my end, this worked! Thanks so much!!

Comment: I have one more question pertaining this that I added in the question above.

Comment: @TerryB you can give each VC a storyboard identifier and access it in code then push it after setting the required value wuth self.navigationController.push instead of the segue

Comment: Ok, right on... I'll have to work on that. You are the best, @Sh_Khan !!